# Use genetic algorithm with WEKA for intrusion detection

Tags: dataset, weka, genetic-algorithm, intrusion-detection

Can I use directly the genetic algorithm on weka for classification attacks in intrusion detection ?
If yes, what is the best data set to use for GA ? because KDD data set is so old ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use genetic algorithms with intrusion detection. Actually it is a popular choice, see [my review article about KDD99 and intrusion detection in peerj preprint](https://peerj.com/preprints/1954/). Genetic algorithms are third most popular choice and are used in 16 times in 2010-2015 among 149 articles, see table 6 in article.

You can also see other popular data set choices in Table 9  Most used Datasets in the same article. Unfortunately, there is no recent popular IDS data set right now. This research gap is given in a lot of IDS review articles. See one of the most recent ones as of May 2016, and you will see.